# "Полон бодрости" или "полон бодростью"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Вроде бы бодрости, как и в "полон сил". Но почему так? Какой вопрос задается к слову? По логике, как мне кажется, должно быть "полон чем? силами".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта приемлемы. И полон чем (бодростью, счастьем, силами, водой, орехами), и полон чего (бодрости, счастья, сил, воды, орехов).

Есть, вроде, небольшая стилистическая разница.
Например, в выражении "стакан полон воды" подчеркивается, что это стакан и что он полный. А в "полон водой, счастьем" - проявляется значение "преисполненный, наполненный" и важно именно то, что водой или счастьем.

В отношении "полон сил" и подобных - тут такое дело. Понятие "быть полным" тут имеет переносное значение, а в этих случаях на первом месте выступает именно объект, который полон, поэтому "полон сил" используется чаще, но и второй вариант совсем не исключен, особенно когда "полон" в прямом значении:
"Город был полон правоохранительными силами" представляется вполне возможным. Тут смысловое ударение идет на "силы".

Все это стилистические тонкости, главное то, что ***оба варианта допустимы***.

(+)

> К разговору о штампах.   //==================
>       Из книги Д.Э. Розенталя "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке":
>          "В разных материалах встречаются одни и те же сочетания, превратившиеся в "стертые пятаки". Таковы сочетания со словом "золото"
>   всякого цвета: "белое золото" (хлопок), "черное золото" (уголь),
>   "голубое золото" (гидроэнергия), "жидкое золото" (нефть)... Другие
>   примеры штампов: "большой хлеб", "большая руда", "большая нефть" (в
>   значении "много...")... К таким "излюбленным" сочетаниям относятся
>   также: "люди в серых шинелях", "люди в зеленых фуражках" (лесники,
>   егеря, пограничники?), "люди в белых халатах" (врачи? продавцы?)".
>          В практической стилистике термин "речевой штамп" получил более узкое значение: так называют стереотипное выражение, имеющее
>   канцелярскую окраску. И здесь прежде всего можно выделить такие
>   шаблонные обороты речи: "на данном этапе", "в данный отрезок времени",
>   "на сегодняшний день", "подчеркнул со всей остротой" и т.п. Как
>   правило, они ничего не вносят в содержание высказывания, а лишь
>   засоряют речь.
>          К речевым штампам относят также универсальные слова, которые используются в самых различных, неопределенных значениях: вопрос,
>   мероприятие, ряд, проводить, разворачивать, отдельный, определенный.
>   Например, существительное "вопрос", выступая как универсальное слово,
>   никогда не указывает на то, о чем спрашивают. Например: "Особо важное
>   значение имеют вопросы питания в первые 10-12 дней" (так в чем же
>   состоит вопрос? о чем, собственно, речь?) Слово "являться", как
>   универсальное, тоже лишнее. Предложение "Очень важным является
>   использование для этой цели химикатов" вполне заменяется более
>   определенным высказыванием "Для этой цели необходимо использовать
>   химикаты".
>          Речевые штампы, избавляя говорящего от необходимости искать нужные точные слова, лишают речь конкретности. "Нынешний сезон провели
>   на высоком организационном уровне" - это предложение можно вставить в
>   отчет и об уборке сена, и о спортивных соревнованиях, и о подготовке
>   жилого фонда к зиме, и о сборе винограда...
>          От речевых штампов следует отличать языковые стандарты.
>          Языковыми стандартами называют готовые, воспроизводимые в речи средства выражения, используемые в публицистическом стиле. В их
>   употреблении нет ничего плохого. В отличие от штампа, они обладают
>   четким смысловым выражением, экономно выражают мысль, способствуют
>   быстроте передачи информации. Это такие сочетания, как "работники
>   бюджетной сферы", "служба занятости", "международная гуманитарная
>   помощь", "коммерческие структуры", "силовые ведомства", "ветви
>   российской власти", "по данным из информированных источников", "служба
>   быта", "служба здоровья" и т.д. Эти речевые единицы широко
>   используются журналистами, так как невозможно в каждом конкретном
>   случае изобретать новые средства выражения.   //=================

Цитирую по
[10. РЕЧЕВЫЕ ШТАМПЫ И ЯЗЫКОВЫЕ СТАНДАРТЫ | Сочинитель.ру](http://sochinitell.ru/node/246)

Можно найти и точные определения, порой весьма отличающиеся по форме, но общие по сути. 
"Речевой штамп" — выражение, лишенное конкретной семантической нагрузки, паразитный, малосодержательный речевой оборот.

Niemand, если я его правильно понимаю (хотя это самом по себе задача непростая), полагает, что речевой штамп — это любое выражение, которое часто употребляют, что в корне неверно. 
Впрочем, если так, он сам себе противоречит, ибо штамп - фигура речи нежелательная, но в тоже самое время частотность (по Niemand'у) определяет и допустимость — чем чаще, тем-де допустимее.

Тут трудно дать какой-то осмысленный комментарий.

Плюс ко всему, "штамп" обычно не допускает осмысленной замены составляющих, пусть и не так императивно, как фразеологизм. Но "полон сил" — вполне себе гибкое выражение, примеры с "полон воды или счастья" я приводил.

Comment: А не проще ли все? Родительный чаще идет в предметном, материальном значении (у вас - воды, орехов), отвлеченное, переносное значение передается чаще творительным (счастьем, силами). Поэтому "полон силами", даже правоохранительными,  сомнительно.

Comment: Вы абзац не дописали, behemothus.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, да, понял. Тут еще техническая накладка произошла, мы одновременно бросились редактировать это сообщение.

Comment: И правда одновременно, простите)

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря грамматической сочетаемости (Е.М. Лазуткина, 2013 год, словари РАН)

Полный, полон (чего?) бодрости. **Используется только Р.п.** (в основном и переносном значениях слова), **Т.п. считается устаревшим** (например, нежелательно говорить: кувшины, полные водой (Т.п.); вечера полны тишиной (Т. п.).

Можно предположить, что в данном случае употребление Р.п. связано с количественной семантикой прилагательного "полный": полно (чего?) воды - много (чего?) воды.

Сравнить: наполнить бассейн **водой**; бассейн, наполненный **водой**; бассейн, полный **воды**, полон **воды**, в нем много **воды**.