# Набить полный рот картофелЯ (или картофелЕМ) — как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, падежи, управление

> — Так вот, он говорит, что по дороге в бутик Лула, сидя на заднем сиденье, что-то писала. Когда вы с ней встретились в «Вашти», она тебе не показывала, не передавала никакой записки?
> — Не-а. — *Рошель набила полный рот картофел**я** фри.* — Ничего такого. А что в ней было-то, в этой записке?
> [**Роберт Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки**](http://loveread.me/read_book.php?id=25524&p=60) (перевод с английского Е. С. Петровой)

Запуталась в собственных рассуждениях. *Набить полный рот — картофе**ля*** или *картофел**ем**?* Подскажите: **как** правильно и **почему**?

Comment: Здесь есть интересные мысли:  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423986/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E/423988#423988

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Да, действительно, интересные мысли есть.

Answer (score 3):

"*Набить **полный** рот (+ наполнитель)*" - некорректное сочетание с глаголом по смыслу, приводящее к рассогласованию падежей "картофеля" (или иного названного наполнителя) - либо с мерой "**полный рот**" (картофел**я**), либо с выражением "**набить рот**" (картофел**ем**). Возможные варианты:

> 1) "набрать полный рот картофеля"
>
> 2) "набить/наполнить рот картофелем"

Comment: А разве нельзя, например, сказать так: набить полный портфель - (чем?) - книгами? Или: набить полный портфель - (чего?) - книг? Здесь ведь  *нужно* "озвучивать" наполнитель. Это ведь могли быть и кирпичи, и патроны (вспомните!).

Comment: "Набить/наполнить полный" - нельзя: для этого нужно взять "полный портфель" и "набить" его книгами, что странно. Портфель, полный книг - это конечное состояние, а не действие.

Answer (score 2):

**Рошель набила полный рот картофелем фри.** Управление: набить (чем?)  картофелем.

Но: **Рошель с полным ртом картофеля говорила с трудом.** Управление: полный (чего?) картофеля.

**Пояснение**

**НАПОЛНИТЬ**,  св. 1. что (чем). **НАБИТЬ**, св. 1. что (кем-чем). **ПОЛНЫЙ**,   1. (**чего**, чем). **НАБРАТЬ**,  св. 1. что и **чего**.

**Набить, наполнить** – здесь глаголы управляют Т.п., а прилагательное ***полный*** может управлять Р.п (или Т.п.).