# Наш мир ТАКИХ ЛЮДЕЙ полон / наш мир ТАКИМИ ЛЮДЬМИ полон

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление, выбор-варианта

*Наш мир **таких людей** полон* или *наш мир **такими людьми** полон* — как правильно написать?

Comment: Вот похожий вопрос на нашем сайте: “Полон бодрости” или “полон бодростью”? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423986/Полон-бодрости-или-полон-бодростью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Попробуем решить задачу, используя только значения падежей,** указанные в Грамматике-80 (поэтому это будет экспериментальное решение).

Интересно, что в Грамматике-80  даны оба варианта: **полный воды и полный водой**. Но семантика для различных прилагательных может быть разной.

**Для Т.п.** с его орудийным значением существительное обозначает **содержимое**: ***полный водой, бедный минералами, славный делами*** и др. Мы не можем сказать: *бедный минералов*.

**Для Р.п.** с его *количественным значением* важно именно количество, а не содержимое: ***полный воды.***

Таким образом, для прилагательного ***полный***  обе формы  допустимы **(количественная и содержательная).**  Возможно, что выбор конкретного варианта зависит **от структуры предложения и расстановки логических ударений в нем.**

(1) Наш мир таких людей **пОлон.** Наш мир  **пОлон** таких людей. Здесь подчеркнуто **количество (заполненность).**  Ударение падает **на прилагательное.**

(2) **ТакИми людьми** наш мир полон. Здесь подчеркнуто **содержимое,** ударение падает на сочетание "такими людьми".

В заданном предложении: **Наш мир такИми людьми полон.**
Здесь применена инверсия, ударение падает на ***такими людьми***.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо за разбор. Понимаю так. Пожалуйста, поправьте если считаете, что не права.
1. Тв. падеж. Мы смотрим на определенного человека — допустим, отзывчивого воспитателя детского сада — и думаем: «Хорошо, что мир ТАКИМИ ЛЮДЬМИ полон». Или смотрим на неприятного нам человек и думаем: «Кошмар, они повсюду. Мир ТАКИМИ ЛЮДЬМИ полон!» Акцент всегда на «такими людьми». Мы как бы привязаны к определенному человеку и проецируем его на мир.
2. Род. падеж. Нет личностного. Нет глубины чувства. «Мир полон таких людей» можно бросить и через плечо.

Comment: Я не совсем так понимаю. Акцент делается или на прилагательном "пОлон" (если "таких людей" ), иди на сочетании "такИми людьми". Встретили хорошего  человека и думаете: он не один, такИми людьми мир полон. Или: он не один, мир пОлон таких людей. Я немного перестраиваю фразу, чтобы ударение было УДОБНО ставить на том слове, которое вы хотите подчеркнуть, выбирая при этом нужный падеж.

Answer (score 2):

**I.** Вот что говорится в словаре управления (Д. И. Розенталь):
[полный (полон)](https://books.google.ee/books?id=4PX8AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD&source=bl&ots=8IWdkstOtl&sig=ACfU3U3S8YRDjHmSNMvAjmQ3LuL0Fci-wg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3vc-cs8DgAhVCz6YKHbM2DhEQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD&f=false) **кого-чего** и **кем-чем**
**1.** **к о г о - ч е г о** (содержащий что-либо; вместивший много кого-либо, чего-либо).
Двор был полон всякой домашней птицы (Гончаров); Кувшин, полный воды; Полный денег карман; На днях получил твоё... полное советов и пропитанное запахом Тулы письмо (Л. Толстой).
**2.** **к е м - ч е м** (наполненный чем-либо доверху, до краев; всецело увлеченный, захваченный кем-либо, чем-либо).
Свидание наше было трогательное: он [Жуковский] весь полон Пушкиным (Гоголь); Борозды пашен и канавы с боков дороги были полны водой (А. Н. Толстой); Душа полна любовью; Сердце полно тобою.
3. **ч е г о** и **ч е м** (целиком проникнутый чем-либо; исполненный чего-либо).
Родина! Особенно звучит для меня это слово, полное глубокого смысла (Соколов-Микитов); Начиналась новая жизнь — полная борьбы, приключений, радости открытий (Ушаков); Со страхом и тоской она в карету села и дорогой была полна мучительной тревогой (Лермонтов).

**II.** Вот говорится в научной статье по специальности «Языкознание» [Выбор падежа зависимого имени при прилагательном «полный»](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/vybor-padezha-zavisimogo-imeni-pri-prilagatelnom-polnyy) (Е. А. Проценюк).

Работа посвящена выявлению тенденций выбора падежа зависимого имени при прилагательном *полный* и установлению факторов, влияющих на этот выбор. Полученные данные позволяют прийти к нескольким выводам: **местоимения и имена собственные выбирают преимущественно форму Т. п., в то время как для всех нарицательных существительных заметно предпочтение формы Р. п., доля которой растет со временем.**

На страницах 290—295 представлены примеры, диаграммы и статистика употребления [*полон людей* (15) / *полон людьми* (12)], из которой можно сделать вывод: в данное время формы родительного и творительного падежей равно употребимы.

***Мир полон людей*** жадных и корыстных (Д. Карнеги).
***А такими людьми полон наш*** так называемый христианский и образованный **мир.** Мало того, что **такими людьми полон наш мир,** — идеал людей нашего христианского образованного мира есть приобретение... (Л. Толстой)

Comment: Римма Михайлова, как найти этот чудо словарь? На него надо подписаться или он доступен без оплаты?

Comment: Вот, Белочка, пользуйтесь на здоровье! http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/punctuation-rosental/index.htm  Найдите "полный" и информация — Ваша. P. S. Надо бы  вопрос "подправить". Вы не против?

Comment: Нисколько! Всем, кто ответил на мой вопрос, благодарна! За сноску к словарям аж кланяюсь. Объявлюсь на этом сайте довольно скоро: у меня с запятыми сплошное танго и подножки. ) Печалит то, что нельзя под каждым комментарием написать «Спасибо!». Подчиняюсь. Но хоть здесь прокричу: «Всем спаси-и-бочки!»

Answer (score 1):

В словарях допускаются оба варианта. Правда, в словаре Ушакова говорится, что творительный падеж в этом значении употребляется реже.

ПОЛНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; полон и (устар.) полн, полна, -о и -о; полнее; полнейший. 1. (чего, чем). Наполненный доверху, занятый целиком. П-ая сумка. П-ая мерка. Налить полную тарелку супа. П-ая корзина ягод. П-ые вёдра брусники. П. до краёв. Озеро, п-ое рыбой. Подойники, п-ые молоком. Руки полны яблок. Борозды полны воды. **2. (кого-чего, кем-чем). Содержащий в себе, вместивший в себя предельное количество кого-, чего-л.** П. автобус, театр. **Дом всегда полон гостями.** **Двор полон всякой птицы.** Газеты полны фельетонов. Слать письма, п-ые советов. Воздух, п. влаги. Дом как п-ая чаша (зажиточный, богатый). Испить полную чашу (испытать что-л. вполне). * Луной был полон сад (Фет). Хлопот полон рот (погов.: о ком-л., у кого очень много хлопот, дел).

**Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.**

2. **без·доп. и чего или (·редк.) чем. Содержащий в себе, вместивший в себя много чего-нибудь. «Театр уж полон.» Пушкин. «С утра дом Лариной гостями весь полон.»** Пушкин. «Все улицы полны народом.» Жуковский. «Полны амбары огромные хлеба.» Жуковский. Руки полны орехов. Полный карман денег. **Карман, полный денег или (·редк.) деньгами.** «Хлопот полон рот.» погов.

**Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.**

Answer (score 0):

Полон (кого-чего), но заполнен или наполнен (кем-чем).

Comment: Думаю, что пример приведён неспроста. Впрочем вопрос пока не задан.

Comment: @shampar, как не задан-то? **«Наш мир таких людей полон» или «наш мир такими людьми полон»** - не вопрос? Ну, знака вопроса нет, это правда.

Comment: Я не вижу. Если видите, поделитесь. Я вижу название. Проблемы нет.

Comment: Ты боже мой... *Как правильно: «Наш мир таких людей полон» или «наш мир такими людьми полон»?* Нельзя же быть таким буквоедом... (

Comment: Я перешёл на личности? Покажите в каком месте перешёл.

Comment: Буквоед - не ругательное слово, а где-то даже почтительное.

Comment: Моё замечание было больше об ответе, который здесь почли недостаточным по объёму. Я решил, что он спровоцирован недостаточностью в самом вопросе.

Comment: Niemand. Значит, «полон» управляет род. падежом, так?  Shampar. Дорогой, уважаемый, проблема же ясна: в какой падеж выводить слова «такой» и «люди». Извините за отсутствие вопросительного знака.

Comment: @Белка Чаще всего да. Почти всегда да.

Answer (score 0):

Хотя оба словоупотребления допустимы, старинная загадка про огурец ("дом без окон, без дверей -- полна горница людей") свидетельствует в пользу родительного падежа.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/26377)

Comment: Это аргумент в пользу предпочтительности родительного падежа.

Comment: Народное творчество, фольклор тут не у дел. Сравните: *Её сестра звалась Татьяна - Итак, она звалась Татьяной*, - вопрос именно об этих формах. Не об огурцах.)))

Comment: Осмелюсь не согласиться. Фольклор является источником стандартов языка в той же мере, что и классика. В этом смысле огурец ничуть не хуже Татьяны.

Comment: @Michael_1812, вы не правы. Об этом свидетельствуют словарные фиксации. Это раз. Во-вторых, одну и ту же модель нельзя применять ко всем случаем.

Comment: А почему оба варианта допустимы? Приведите доказательства, пожалуйста.